# Merging nested object fields into a single nested array field in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, aggregate, grouping

As part of my aggregation pipeline I have the following scenario. This is the result of grouping previously unwound fields from each document (so in this case there are two documents with the same _id but with a different value for UniqueFieldName)

```
    TopLevelField: [
        {
            UniqueFieldName: "Values go here!"
        },
        {
            UniqueFieldName: "More values go here too!"
        }
    ]
```

All I want to do is merge the nested object fields into one field and push all the values into that field as an array, like so.

```
    TopLevelField: {
        UniqueFieldName: [
             "Values go here!",
             "More values go here too!",
        ],
    }
```

The idea is that I could have multiple fields with multiple values under each field grouped together for easier iteration.

```
    TopLevelField: {
        UniqueFieldName: [
             "Values go here!",
             "More values go here too!",
        ],
        SecondFieldName: [
             "This is text",
        ],
        AnotherOne: [
             "TEXT",
             "Here too!",
             "More values",
        ],
    }
```

The problem I run into is that trying to use dot notation in the $group stage throws an error. It seems that mongo doesn't like to group with nested objects like this?

The easy solution is to just change the TopLevelField to some concatenation of the nested fields like this,

```
    TopLevelField-UniqueFieldName: [
         "Values go here!",
         "More values go here too!",
    ],
    TopLevelField-SecondFieldName: [
         "This is text",
    ],
    TopLevelField-AnotherOne: [
         "TEXT",
         "Here too!",
         "More values",
    ],
```

But this is suboptimal for my use case. Is there a solution to this or do I need to rethink the entire pipeline?

Comment: Do you mean to say there will be random fields inside `TopLevelField` ?

Comment: Yes, there could be any number of subfields under TopLevelField. I'd just like to group the same fields together into a single array instead of having an array of objects.

Comment: So do you know the field names or those names are random which you can't name in query (un-predictable names & count of subfields)?

Comment: I'll know all the names and can easily reference them programmatically. They're random in the sense that the user can select as many fields as they like in any combination but all of that is part of the pipeline.

Comment: Yes if you know the names of subfields you can do another group to get these fields values pushed into an array for each subfields.. Let me know if that's the case I can give you a query if you need.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I need! Every query I've tried doesn't like the fact that I'm trying to group on a subfield so if you could help with the query for that I'd be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$TopLevelField' },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '', 'UniqueFieldName': { $push: '$TopLevelField.UniqueFieldName' },
            'UniqueFieldName2': { $push: '$TopLevelField.UniqueFieldName2' },
            'UniqueFieldName3': { $push: '$TopLevelField.UniqueFieldName3' },
            'UniqueFieldName4': { $push: '$TopLevelField.UniqueFieldName4' }
        }
    }, { $project: { _id: 0 } }, { $project: { 'TopLevelField': '$$ROOT' } }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cpr09mWL7rV)

Comment: This will work perfectly for me! I never thought to replace the root like that! Thank you so much!